# Using variables in quotes

Tags: javascript, html, var, html2pdf

I am using the html2pdf libary from [Github](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf)

I can define the filename like this:

```
<i>filename:   "filename.pdf"</i>
```

In my case I have to use a variable insted of a fixed name.

```
 <script>
      $(function()
      {});

      function printPDF()
      {
          var element = document.getElementById("element-to-print");
          var opt = {
              margin:       1,
              filename:     "filename.pdf";
              image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.99 },      
              html2canvas:  { scale: 2 },
              jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation:  'portrait'}
          };

          // New Promise-based usage:
          html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).save();
      }
</script>
```

Comment: `filenameVar+".pdf"` ? Are you having trouble passing a variable as an argument or having trouble making a string from variables ?

Comment: @CodyＧ I tested this already but it do not work. He do not create a pdf after this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a filename as function parameter and use it like this `printPDF('myFile.pdf')`  :

```
  function printPDF(filename) {
     {
      var element = document.getElementById("element-to-print");
      var opt = {
          margin:       1,
          filename,
          image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.99 },      
          html2canvas:  { scale: 2 },
          jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation:  'portrait'}
      };

      // New Promise-based usage:
      html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).save();
  }
```

Comment: I am using a button to execute this function. If I use your code and use the button like this it do not work:

<button id="snbtn" type="submit" class="w3-btn w3-green"  onclick="printPDF('myFile.pdf');">Abschicken</button>